# Traefik access logs on console as well as file

Tags: traefik

We are using traefik 2.2.1

When we use

```
[accessLog]
  format = "json"
```

It prints logs only on console.

When we use

```
[accessLog]
  filePath = "/var/log/traefik/access.log"
  format = "json"
```

It prints logs only in the file.

However, we want traefik to print logs to console as well as log file.

How can we achieve that?